# CoffeeScript replace equal signs substring

Tags: coffeescript

Trying to replace equal sign characters in a string with an escaped equal sign character in coffee script (for use with calling pip via Fabric).

== should become \=\=

```
coffee> "==".replace /\=\=/, "=="
'=='
coffee> "==".replace /\=\=/, "\=\="
'=='
coffee> "==".replace /\=\=/, "\\=\\="
'\\=\\='
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last one is probably correct. It just prints funny. Try x.length to confirm (should be four).

```
coffee> "==".replace(/\=\=/, "\\=\\=").length
4
```